# How to write a require statement in Perl to get the %EXPORT_TAGS from a module?

Tags: perl

I need to convert a 'use' statement in my Perl code to 'require' statement to import some %EXPORT_TAGS from another module. The module that I am "use"ing is a plain .pm file (not a class with constructor).

Below is the snippet of the MyModule.pm file

```
package MyModule;
use Exporter qw(import);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'tag1' => [qw (func1 func2)],
                     'tag2' => [qw (func3 func4)]
                    );
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw (func1 func2 func3 func4); 

sub func1 {
  #some statement
}

# similary other functions written ...
```

The "use" statement that I have tried from my script looks like below:

```
use MyModule qw(:tag1 :tag2);
```

Now I need to convert it to a "require" statement. I tried what is suggested [here](https://perlmaven.com/use-require-import) as below but of no help :

```
require MyModule;
MyModule->import;
```

One Limitation, that is :
This MyModule.pm is used in other scripts by "use" statement so I cannot remove %EXPORT_TAGS and @EXPORT_OK;

Any help to write me the correct and working "require" syntax will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want to `use`? Is it an expensive module that you only need sometimes, so you want to load it at run time conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use` statement basically translates to a `BEGIN` block with an `import` call, where the argument list is passed into `import`.

So this would translate to

```perl
require MyModule;
MyModule->import(qw/ :tag1 :tag2 /);
```

It doesn't matter if it's tags, or function names, or variable names. The only special case is if you have `use Foo ()` with an empty argument list, in which case there will not be an `import` call at all.

Comment: I know that, But I need a explicit require statement

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast I don't understand what the problem is. You asked for how to import things exported by Exporter. This is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

This `use` statement:

```
use MyModule qw(:tag1 :tag2);
```

is this `require`:

```
BEGIN {
    require MyModule;
    MyModule->import( qw(:tag1 :tag2) );
    }
```

Without the `BEGIN`, the module isn't loaded until Perl encounters that statement during run time, which might be too late for the code that wants to use the things you want to import.

If you explained why you need `require`, we could probably clear up that problem.